# split all character using javascript except '\t','\b','\n'

Tags: javascript

var str = "\tToday we are going to\b a farm to pick\r" i want to";
str.split('');

```js
var str = "\tToday we are going to\b a farm to pick\r";
var result = str.split('');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

But in result '\t', '\r','\b' replacing by symbol, like for '\t' its taking big space.
Help to get as array like 
[  "\t",  "T",  "o",  "d",  "a",  "y",  " ",  "w",  "e",  " ",  "a",  "r",  "e",  " ",  "g",  "o",  "i",  "n",  "g",  " ",  "t",  "o",  "\b",  " ",  "a",  " ",  "f",  "a",  "r",  "m",  " ",  "t",  "o",  " ",  "p",  "i",  "c",  "k",  "\r"]

Thanks

Comment: so you want to replace special characters (\t == tab, \b == backspace, \r == carriage return) with string literals \t, \b, \r etc? - because I can assure you that result[0] === '\t' for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But in result '\t', '\r','\b' replacing by symbol, like for '\t' its taking big space

If you're outputting this to a terminal console, that's just because `\t` is a **tab**, and the console output is outputting a tab, which the terminal is interpreting as a number of spaces. Similar (but different, and possibly more surprising) things will happen with `\r` and `\b`.

> Help to get as array like...

That's what you're getting, it's just that when you output to the console, the output is interpreted by the terminal.

If you want to see actual backslashes, you could run the entries through `JSON.stringify`, but I suspect you don't. I think you probably want the array you already have.